# Dynamically pass prop without any value in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am completely new to react native. Currently exploring the react native vector icons for FontAwesome 5 pro icons.

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons

There are 3 types of icon sets for FontAwesome 5 such as regular, solid and light.

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';

const myIcon1 = <Icon name="comments" size={30} color="#900" />; // Defaults to regular
const myIcon2 = <Icon name="comments" size={30} color="#900" solid />;
const myIcon3 = <Icon name="comments" size={30} color="#900" light />; // Only in FA5 Pro
```

Is there any way I can pass the icon type (light, solid) dynamically?

I have tried the following so far:

```
let iconType = focused ? 'solid' : 'light';

return <Icon name="comments" size={30} color="#900" {...iconType} />;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `solid` props takes a `boolean` value (which defaults to `false` if you dont pass it), which means

```js
<Icon name="comments" size={30} color="#900" solid />
<Icon name="comments" size={30} color="#900" />
```

is short for,

```js
<Icon name="comments" size={30} color="#900" solid={true} />
<Icon name="comments" size={30} color="#900" solid={false} />
```

For your case, you can try this

```js
<Icon name="comments" size={30} color="#900" solid={focused} light={!focused} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to create a reusable custom component to tackle your issue, something like this

```
const GetIcon = props => {
  return (
    <Icon name={props.name} size={30} color="#900" solid={props.focused} light={!props.focused} />
  );
};
```

and then call your components like this in side your class

```
<GetIcon name="comments" focused={true}/>
```

for more info on reusable components read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55059348/how-to-use-universal-footer-for-all-screens-in-nativebase/55059773#55059773)

Comment: Is it similar to `return <Icon name="comments" size={30} color="#900" {iconType} />;`? This not working for me.

Comment: Make sure you put it outside the class this is `stateless` reusable component example is given here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55059348/how-to-use-universal-footer-for-all-screens-in-nativebase/55059773#55059773

Answer (score 0):

The `{...iconType}` is object spread syntax, it means you spread your object and pass it to component as `key=value`, and it doesn't make sense because `iconType` is a string.

As far as I know, there is no way to set an JSX attribute like your expectation. Instead, you could check condition before you return the component:

```
return focused ? 
        <Icon name="comments" size={30} color="#900" solid /> : 
        <Icon name="comments" size={30} color="#900" light/>;
```

Comment: Already using this approach. Looking for a solution where I don't have to pass the whole component.